# Trying to change the CKEditor getSelection() range programmatically to get all data for a plugin

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have modified an existing core plugin for CKeditor called Remove Format.   This version is designed just to remove Style attributes and a few tags.

I have setup a event trigger on afterPaste, which I want to basically run against the whole editor instance on that event.

The lines i need to edit are

```
ranges = editor.getSelection().getRanges(),
iterator = ranges.createIterator(),
isElement = function( element ) {
    return element.type == CKEDITOR.NODE_ELEMENT;
},
range;


while ( ( range = iterator.getNextRange() ) ) {
```

I have made several attempts to just change the selection of ranges using concepts from the API.

```
ranges = new CKEDITOR.dom.range( editor.document );
```

But nothing has panned out.
I need to get the object for all ranges in the document, which contains the createIterator() function, so I can iterate using the iterator.getNextRange() function on the whole document.

Any ideas.    I also tried incorporating the SelectAll plugin, but that also has not panned out.

Comment: If you just want to disallow styles and elements, you can use [Disallowed Content](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_disallowed_content.html)

Comment: Yes that is true, but i only want to do it on Paste.   I don't want to effect other elements built using the CkEditor.